# Not getting Webhook Notifications for Sent Items folder

Tags: office365, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using the MS Graph API to set a web hook that notifies our app when a message hits a user's inbox, or sent folder.   The inbox notifications work great, but I can't seem to get notifications for the Outbox or Sent Items.   I'm getting a valid subscription ID, using the code below.   I'm just not sure why I'm not seeing any notifications come through.

```
        {
          "changeType": "created",
          "notificationUrl": "{myPath}",
          "resource": "/me/mailfolders('Sent Items')/messages",
          "expirationDateTime": "{myExp}",
          "clientState": "{usrEmail}"
        }
```

Also, is it possible to monitor 2-folders with one subscription?  By doing something like this...

```
        { 
          "changeType": "created",
          "notificationUrl": "{myPath}",
          "resource": "/me/mailfolders('Inbox','Sent Items')/messages",
          "expirationDateTime": "{myExp}",
          "clientState": "{usrEmail}"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also got in this trouble, but I have found a solution:
in the official documentation of
[mailFolder resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mailfolder) there is description of `id` property:

> The mailFolder's unique identifier. You can use the following well-known names to access the corresponding folder: Inbox, Drafts, SentItems, DeletedItems.

By experimental way I have find next working id's for mail folders:

```
Inbox
Drafts
SentItems
DeletedItems
JunkEmail
```